# Angular calendar how to custom events template

Tags: angular, angular-calendar

I am using Angular calendar to implement day view for my project. I need to show a certain time of day with different background color.

I need to specify tasks list for events in my calendar.

Do you know how to use ng-emplate for custom events ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

**Below links will help you design and develop custom calendar**
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-calendar-zmhuap?file=demo%2Ftemplate.html

https://angular-calendar.com/docs/components/CalendarMonthViewComponent.html#beforeViewRender

[angular-calendar having a show more options to load more events in a day cell of the month view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57196544/angular-calendar-having-a-show-more-options-to-load-more-events-in-a-day-cell-of)